# debug_traceTransaction says tx failed, etherscan says passed

Tags: transaction-trace

I was running `debug_traceTransaction` on the transactions in the first 100,000 blocks, and I came across 25 that were flagged as failed, but etherscan.io says they are fine.  The gas used is below gas, and there are no bad opcodes or jumps, so I would also say they are fine.  Here are a few of them (`blocknum:txindex`):

```
49170:0
54213:2
78902:0
```

The only thing the 25 have in common is that they are all contract creations. Why are they flagged as failed?